# Polylogarithm integral

Tags: integration, summation

Are these two equal? (mathematica says NO):

$$\int_0^e\text{Li}_2\left(\ln(x)\right)\space\text{d}x=\sum_{\text{k}=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\text{k}^2}\int_0^e\ln^\text{k}\left(x\right)\space\text{d}x$$

But I do not understand why they aren't?

Comment: $$ \text{Li}_2(z) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{z^n}{n^2} $$ only if $|z|<1$ and $|\log x|$ is way bigger than one in a neighbourhood of zero. You are assuming that $\text{Li}_2(z)$ is an entire function, but it isn't.

Comment: Oke, but how can I find a series that I can use outside that range?

Comment: You have to perform a analytic continuation through the reflection formulas (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html), for instance.

Comment: Is there a series that is defined for all Li_n(X)?? Because what you stages above I dont understand

Comment: That is not possible, since $\text{Li}_n(z)$ has singularities on the boundary of the unit disk. As said before, $\text{Li}_n$ **is not** an entire function. Just to make it clear, there is the same issue of defining $\arctan(2)$ as $2-\frac{2^3}{3}+\frac{2^5}{5}-\ldots$: the last series is not converging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{z^n}{n^2} \tag{1}$$
defines $\text{Li}_2(z)$ just over the domain $|z|<1$: if $|z|>1$, such a series is not convergent.
However, you may exploit the reflection formula
$$\text{Li}_2(1-z) + \text{Li}_2(1-z^{-1})=-\frac{1}{2}\log^2(z) \tag{2} $$
to state that
$$\begin{eqnarray*} &\phantom{=}&\int_{0}^{e}\text{Li}_2(\log x)\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^{1}e^u\,\text{Li}_2(u)\,dx=\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{1-v}\,\text{Li}_2(1-v)\,dv\\&=&\int_{0}^{1}e^v\,\text{Li}_2(v)\,dv-\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{+\infty}\log^2(v)e^{1-v}\,dv-\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{+\infty}e^{1-v}\,\text{Li}_2(1-v^{-1})\,dv\\&=&\int_{0}^{1}\left(e^v-\frac{e^{-v/(1-v)}}{v^2}\right)\,\text{Li}_2(v)\,dv-\frac{e}{2}\int_{1}^{+\infty}\log^2(v)e^{-v}\,dv.\tag{3}\end{eqnarray*} $$
$\text{Li}_2(v)$ can now be expressed as a power series, since $v$ ranges over $(0,1)$.